# доступ к скрипту php через wordpress

Tags: wordpress

есть сайт на вордпрессе и есть файл test.php. хочу что бы его функции исполнялись только если пользователь зарегистрирован и наделен нужными полномочиями. насколько верно и безопасно будет сделать это так-

```html
    <?php
require_once( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/wp-load.php' );
if ( is_user_logged_in() && current_user_can('administrator')) {
 echo 'Вы авторизованы на сайте и являетесь администратором!';
}
else {
 header('Location:/wp-login.php');
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все нормально, так делать можно и это безопасно.

Answer (score 0):

Небольшое дополнение: если нужно выполнять код не только для Администратора, но и всем, кто обладает полномочиями можно использовать следующий код:

```
if(current_user_can('manage_options')) :
  echo "Вы авторизованы и обладаете достаточными полномочиями";
endif;
```

Comment: а как узнать кто ими обладает?

Comment: manage_options обладают все, кто имеет право редактировать настройки WP. Если Вы не редактировали права и не создавали новые группы, то только Администраторы.